# Use logarithmic differentiation to find the derivative of y = (cos(x))^ln(x)

Tags: calculus, derivatives, implicit-differentiation

Okay so this question is on my exam study guide for Calculus 1, and I'm having trouble getting to an answer. Here are the steps I have tried currently.

1. Given: $y = (cos(x))^ln(x)$
2. Logarithmic differentiation: $ln(y) = ln(cos(x)^ln(x))$
3. Simplify: $(1/y)*(dy/dx) = ln(x) * ln(cos(x))$
4. Simplify: $(1/y)*(dy/dx) = (1/x) * ln(cos(x))$
5. Product Rule: $(1/y)*(dy/dx) = (1/x) * ln(cos(x)) + (ln(cos(x)))' * ln(x)$
6. Chain Rule: $(1/y)*(dy/dx) = (1/x)*ln(cos(x)) + [1/cos(x) * -sin(x) * ln(x)]$
7. Answer: $(dy/dx) = y((1/x)*ln(cos(x)) + [1/cos(x) * -sin(x) * ln(x)])$

Can someone help as to see where I went wrong in my thinking here

Comment: This is not an answer to your question, but, just to point out, logarithmic differentiation is a lot harder than just learning the rule.  Unfortunately, most Calc books don't even list the rule in the reference.  The rule is:

$$ d(u^v) = v\,u^{v - 1}\,du + \ln(u)\,u^v\,dv $$

If you notice, it is a combination of the regular power rule and the regular exponential rule.

Comment: @Colorful Mess, please spend time editing the question, it doesn't look like it has been edited properly.

Answer (score 2):

$$\begin{align}y=(\cos x)^{\ln x}&\implies \ln y=\ln x\ln(\cos x)\quad\boxed{\text{take logs and use that}\, \ln(a^b)=b\ln a}\\&\implies \overbrace{\frac1y\cdot\frac{dy}{dx}}^{\text{chain rule}}=\overbrace{\frac1x\ln(\cos x)+\ln x\cdot\left(\underbrace{\frac1{\cos x}\cdot(-\sin x)}_{\text{chain rule}}\right)}^{\text{product rule}}\\&\implies \frac{dy}{dx}=(\cos x)^{\ln x}\left(\frac{\ln(\cos x)}x-\tan x\ln x\right)\quad\boxed{\text{simplify}}\end{align}$$

Comment: Firstly how did you format your answer so nicely. Secondly can you add some explanations as to what you did. Thank you for the speedy response by the way

Comment: @RobertLD https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: Hope this is better :)

Answer (score 1):

we get $$\frac{y'}{y}=\frac{1}{x}\ln(\cos(x))+\ln(x)\cdot \frac{1}{\cos(x)}\cdot (-\sin(x))$$